# Convert blank .txt file to PDF in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I am converting a .txt to .pdf in c#. This works fine if the .txt file is not blank. if it is, it threw an error of "The document has no pages".

The pdf gets generated but threw an error of "There was an error opening this document. The file is damaged and could not be repaired" when opening a pdf file.

Code is seen below

```
  public void converttxttoPDF(string sourcePath, string destPath)
    {
        try
        {
            iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
            string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sourcePath);
            System.IO.StreamReader myFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(sourcePath);
            string myString = myFile.ReadToEnd();
            myFile.Close();
            if (!Directory.Exists(destPath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(destPath);
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(destPath + "\\" + filename + ".pdf", FileMode.CreateNew));
            document.Open();
            document.Add(new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(myString));
            document.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

let me know if any info needed.

thanks

Comment: Do you really want a blank PDF to get generated?  What possible use could that have?  Why not check the text file for content first, and throw a messagebox if it's blank?

Comment: @MAW: I understand that it is of no use to generate a blank PDF, but you know the testers, they test everything..LOL :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add some content to the pdf. So try this:

```
myString = string.IsNullOrEmpty(myString) ? " " : myString;
document.Add(new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(myString));
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. but that still threw the same error! :-(

Comment: @Xor power: What error? This works for me. What version of iTextSharp are you using?

Comment: Btw, maybe you would want to close the `writer` too.

Comment: @Ziacik: The version of iTextSharp is 5.0.5.0. Your last comment doesn't get into my head.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convince iText that there IS something on that page.

Two Methods:

1. Be explicit.  `writer.setPageEmpty(false);`
2. Trick it (which is what Darin suggests).  `writer.getDirectContent().setLiteral(" ");`